Does it pay to put effort in fixing this problem or better reinstall Ubuntu 24.04 from scratch?
What happened before:
apt-get -f install returns with "E: Encountered a section with no Package: header"
As Teamviewer still didn’t work, I tried
sudo dpkg --audit

gave msgs:
Die folgenden Pakete befinden sich durch schwere Probleme bei der Installation
in einem Schlamassel. Sie müssen neu installiert werden, damit sie
(und alle von ihnen abhängende Pakete) ordnungsgemäß funktionieren:
 teamviewer           (keine Beschreibung vorhanden)

Die folgenden Pakete wurden entpackt, aber noch nicht konfiguriert.
Sie müssen mit dpkg --configure oder dem Konfigurations-Menüeintrag in
dselect konfiguriert werden, damit sie ordnungsgemäß funktionieren: ...

As this looked too complicate, I decided to uninstall Teamviewer
sudo apt-get purge teamviewer
this returned with msgs:
Messages: 
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes teamviewer (--remove):
 Paket ist in einem sehr schlechten inkonsistenten Zustand - Sie sollten
 es erneut installieren, bevor Sie es zu entfernen versuchen.
dpkg: Zu viele Fehler, Abbruch
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 teamviewer
Bearbeitung wurde angehalten, da zu viele Fehler auftraten.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

According to the advice just given I tried first to reinstall Teamviewer, to be able to uninstall afterward:
wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./teamviewer_amd64.deb
Messages:
…
Die folgenden Pakete werden aktualisiert (Upgrade):
  teamviewer
1 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
209 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 95,3 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 388 MB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
dpkg: nicht behebbarer fataler Fehler, Abbruch:
Laden der Dateilisten-Datei des Paketes »teamviewer«: /var/lib/dpkg/info/teamvie
wer.list ist keine reguläre Datei
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

My question is, does it pay to invest more energy and time in fixing this problem or is it better to install the complete Ubuntu 24.04 from scratch? This reminds me of Windows 95 times.
I want to mention that I am not familiar with Ubuntu, e.g., I would need a straight forward step-by-step instruction that can be executed without further understanding or additional research.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Please translate the German text as AU is an English only site...

Does it pay to invest more energy and time in fixing this problem or is it better to install the complete Ubuntu 24.04 from scratch?
Fixing is worthwhile if you wish to learn more about how the system works.
Reinstalling is preferable if you merely want a working system immediately.
